# Why should I check the return value of operator NEW?

Tags: c++

Meyers in his book "`50 ways to improve..."` second edition writes that I must check return type of new, but I know that if `operator NEW` can't allocate memory it throws `exception`, so with newer libraries I don't need to check return value of new, am I right? thanks in advance

Comment: I just skimmed through item 7. It's titled "Be prepared for out-of-memory conditions" and clearly advices to handle `std::bad_alloc`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I think you're correct: the modern libraries usually throw exceptions for this. But if you're distributing source, some compilers still return NULL rather than throwing an exception. In those situations, it can be useful, but it really depends whether you're going to be there to debug it and how critical the stability of this program is.

Also, someone else pointed out that this is such an obscure problem nowadays that the burden is on the person using the ancient compiler.

Comment: specifically, what compilers return 0? They're either ancient and hence pre-standard, or else have decided (for whatever reason) not to follow the standard. If you're distributing source which you describe as standard C++, anybody receiving it has no grounds to expect it to work on something which doesn't behave like a standard C++ compiler. I think it's *bad* to check for this, unless there are specific reasons to support a particular dodgy compiler, because it clutters the code with rubbish.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. Checking for NULL as a result from a new gives a false sense of security and may also mislead a maintainer that the original developer was expecting new to return NULL and thus cause confusion. You should program to the standard.

Comment: I was trying to explain why someone might do this, but I may have fallen into the trap of justifying the author too much. I had a compiler that would do this a while ago (but don't remember which). I agree, this is almost never done with new, and it does add a lot of clutter, especially considering it should be exception-handled code, too.

Answer (score 0):

No, because C++ allows new to also return NULL on failure.

> $5.3.4/13 - "[Note: unless an
>   allocation function is declared with
>   an empty exception-specification
>   (15.4), throw(), it indicates failure
>   to allocate storage by throwing a
>   bad_alloc exception (clause 15,
>   18.4.2.1); it returns a non-null pointer otherwise. **If the allocation
>   function is declared with an empty
>   exception-specification, throw(), it
>   returns null to indicate failure to
>   allocate storage and a non-null
>   pointer otherwise. ]** If the allocation
>   function returns null, initialization
>   shall not be done, the deallocation
>   function shall not be called, and the
>   value of the new-expression shall be
>   null.

Comment: Thats a bit context free. What is, in the context of that, an allocation function?  A naive reader might guess that that means malloc() or whatever function operator new uses internally - but the function used by operator new is an implementation detail hidden from the end-programmer. In which case the 'allocation function' must be operator new itself? And the standard operator new always throws exceptions (since 2003) unless invoked as: new(std::nothrow) ...;

Comment: @Chris Becke: I think the library may have it's own custom allocator which would be used by new and hence there is a possibility for it to return NULL instead of throwing an exception. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're talking about `operator new(nothrow)` here, not the regular `operator new` . Both belong to the class of allocation functions. C++ doesn't "allow" the regular new to return NULL - it may never - nor does it "allow" `operator new(nothrow)` to return NULL - it **must** return NULL on failure.